# How can one interactivley discard modifications (similarly to `git add -p`)

Tags: git

How can one discard modifications from tracked files similarly to what `git add -p` does with the index? That is I have modified a tracked file and want to undo only parts of the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can use

```
git checkout -p
```

to undo parts of a tracked file (see [git checkout](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html)):

> you can use `git checkout -p` to selectively discard edits from your current working tree.

**Example Output**

```
$ git checkout -p
diff --git a/foo.txt b/foo.txt
index 98d8da3..dfd6895 100644
--- a/foo.txt
+++ b/foo.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Hello world
+Hello world!
Discard this hunk from worktree [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]?
```

Comment: Adding the relevant quote from the documentation: "you can use `git checkout -p` to selectively discard edits from your current working tree."

Comment: You can actually edit your own answer, but I went ahead and added it in as you requested anyways ;)

Answer (score -1):

To unstage interactively, use `git add -i` and the "revert" command on staged commits -- interface is a bit different from the `git add -p`, but basically can do the same thing reversed.

Other (less convenient) possibility is `git add -e` and editing the patch by hand (deleting +lines and removing - from -lines).

Comment: I am not talking about unstaging but reverting modifications of a file.